# Spring Application.properties, can value of a key be another key with value?

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

Would it be possible to define like this in a spring boot application.properties file

```
a.property = value
${value} = another Value
```

If yes, how to resolve a.property in the spring using @Value annotation?

Comment: Why can’t the second key be simply the value? You don’t know the value?

Comment: Yes, I don't have a way to know the value.

Comment: YAML doesn’t support dynamic keys. You’ll have to do it in code.